# Math - Adding with PHP

Tags: php, math

Basically I can't get it right.

I need something like this:

```
if($p == 1)
{
    $start = 0;
    $limit = 16;
}
```

The numbers must add on depending on the value of the $p, e.g. if $p is 5 then the values of $start and $limit would be:

```
if($p == 5)
{
    $start = 64;
    $limit = 80;
}
```

The math is to add 16, depending on the value of $p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$start = ($p - 1) * 16;
$limit = $start + 16;
```

And don't forget to add a test for when `$p < 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = ($p - 1) * 16;
$limit = $p * 16;
```